# 401 with bearer token only auth in .NET Core 3.1 using Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement Bearer token (only) authentication in a .NET Core 3.1 API, using Azure AD.

I'm able to retrieve a token from Azure AD after verifying the `authorization_code` and the browser posts back to my redirect URL with the following:

`{"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"User.Read","expires_in":3600,"ext_expires_in":3600,"access_token":"EwBwA8l6...SzT3qoxGbSMg=="}` (shortened)

Once I have this token, should I be able to use the `[Authorize]` attribute directly on my APIs and request using a Bearer token in the header? When I do, I get a 401 response.

I have this in my `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Audience = "<guid>";

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc123")),
        TokenDecryptionKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc123"))
    };
});
services.AddControllers();
```

And in `Configure()` I have:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In my error log, the message I'm seeing is:

> "Bearer" was not authenticated. Failure message: "No SecurityTokenValidator available for token

I've tried many, many combinations of settings in Startup.cs, and no matter what I can only seem to get a 401 when calling my API from Postman. I'm able to get Cookie authentication working with code samples I've found online, but I don't want that.

Is the issue that the token is encrypted? Am I trying to use the wrong token? Or is there some other issue? Do I need to have identity set up in my app with database tables for AspNetUser, etc.?

In short, I'm just trying to generate a Bearer token using Azure AD as the auth provider, and make calls to my APIs by passing in a Bearer token header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks a bit like you are trying to use a Microsoft Graph API token in your API. (based on this: `"scope":"User.Read"`)

Your front-end app needs to use a scope for your API, not User.Read.
This way it will get an access token which is meant for your API.
Register a scope on your API app registration through the Expose an API section and use the full scope value in your front-end when acquiring the token.

Your back-end needs the following config:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    // add v2.0 to the end if your API is set to get v2 tokens in its manifest
    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-aad-tenant-id";
    options.Audience = "your-api-client-id";
});
```

This should be the minimum configuration needed for authentication.
It'll look up signing keys etc. automatically from the authority at startup.

Comment: Thanks. I added that scope, and the redirect now produces `{"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"api://[guid]/Skills.Read","expires_in":3600,"ext_expires_in":3600,"access_token":"ey...xfdf="}`. When putting that token in the request header I get the error: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key.

Comment: Did you update the authority to the AAD tenant you use in the front-end? :)

Comment: Sorry, I think you lost me. :\

Comment: I mean in your back-end authentication config, did you set the Authority with your tenant id? And remove the token validation parameters?

Comment: Oh! I think I got it now. I updated the Authority URL and once I did that, I got an error about the issuer not being valid. I set ValidateIssuer=false and that works (I'll fix that, but I just wanted to get it working.) Thank you SO much!

Comment: Yeah.. you'll want to validate the issuer. Unless your app is multi-tenant (is it?).

Comment: What's the authority that your front-end uses? :)